# Looking for replace Object.entries() with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I created such a code (and it works locally in Google Chrome but doesn't work on AWS) :

```
    parameters: {
      'forces': 100,
      'hit': 5,
      'defense': 5
    }
<Parameters params={this.props.parameters}/>
   //In render method:
   //console.log(this.props.params); "produces: Object{forces:100, hit:5, defence:5}"
const bars = Object.entries(this.props.params).map(([key,value]) => {
  return (
    <ProgressBar 
      key={key}
      property={key} 
      value={Number(value)} />  
  )
}); 
return (
  <div className="Parameters">
    {bars}
  </div>
);
```

Based on this information:
 [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)
how to create the equal code using old-fashion code:

```
const bars = [];
const obj = this.props.params;
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
//console.log(key, obj[key]);
bars.push()

}
```

The "bars" array should have 3 Progress Bar Components... I created this project just for my own educational purposes and would like to learn different approaches.

Link to this app: [Alex Pilugin: React-Game](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/alexpifirstbucket/react-game/index.html) (it works in Chrome, not in Safari)

[image]

Comment: Why it doesn't work on AWS?

Comment: TypeError: Object.entries is not a function. (In 'Object.entries(this.props.params) ... in Safari (and it works in Google Chrome) - this problem in browser (not AWS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace it with `Object.keys`, since `Object.entries` is not supported yet in Safari.

```
const bars = [];
Object.keys(this.props.params).forEach(key => {
  const value = this.props.params[key];
  bars.push(
   <ProgressBar 
     key={key}
     property={key} 
     value={Number(value)} />  
   );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries` is an [ES2017 Draft proposal](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.entries). ([Full Doc](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262))

You'll need a polyfill for cross-browser support.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I understand it but I don't know how to add polyfill in my project or how to right code on ES2015...